# help with regex pattern

Tags: php, regex

i have multiple strings containing a link like:

```
 <A HREF="http://www.testings2">testings2</A>
 <A HREF="http://www.blabla">blabla</A>
 <A HREF="http://www.gowick">gowick</A>
```

i want to use a regex pattern that gets the uri within the href.

i could do like:

```
 /".*?"/
```

but then the "" will come along. is there a way to just get the uri within the HREF="" without using preg_replace function?

thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
preg_match_all('/href="([^"]+)/i', $str, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

Comment: your regex won't match the examples strings in my answer.

Comment: actually it is. show complete code so we can see the proof of your words

Comment: why don't you test your regex against my examples strings and see. also, while OP's case is simple, your regex is greedy and will fail if there are many `href` in one line

Comment: it not fails in multiple href's in one line, and it's not greedy just because it's [^"].
it worked with expected set of urls. ps: try check yours with HREF in lowercase, lol. and with lowercased </a>.

Comment: my code works with expected set of urls. and yours failed on </a>. dude, before criticize me - fix your "code". actually you get as input terrible set of cr*p, but in question it was proper html.

Comment: sure, my code works on expected set of urls, plus malformed strings as well. if you don't like to be criticized, then don't come here.

Comment: so - get yet another malformed string: <A HrEF="http://www.lol">testings2</a> <A HReF="http://www.lol2">blabla</a> parse it with your code. good luck.

Comment: so i paste the sample malformed string to your post. fix it. after you will - we can continue here.

Comment: and so i did. now go fix yours.

Comment: you don't added "class" into any url.

Comment: $str = preg_replace('![\r\n]!', '', $str);
preg_match_all('/href="([^"]+)/i', $str, $matches);

and this is mine, fixed ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
$str=<<<EOF
 <A href="http://
www.testings2">testings2</A> blah
 <A HrEF=
"http://www.blabla">blabla</A> blah
 <A HREF="http://www.gowick">gowick</A>
 <A
HREF="http://www.testing3">testing3</A>
<a class="navigation" id="selected" href="http://somewhere.com"><xsl:value-of
select="title" /></a>
EOF;

$s = preg_split("/<\/A>/i",$str);
$s = preg_replace("/\n+/","",$s);
$uris = preg_grep("/HREF/i",$s);
foreach($uris as $v){
  $fin = explode('">',$v);
  $t=preg_split('/href="/i',$fin[0] );
  print end($t)."\n";
}
```

output

```
# php test.php
http://www.testings2
http://www.blabla
http://www.gowick
http://www.testing3
http://somewhere.com
```

Comment: lol. explode + strpos + preg_replace. @ghostdog74, your idea was to use as much string functions as you can apply to this task? ;-))

Comment: Yeah, regex matching mechanisms are appropriate for this problem, not crazy string manipulations.

Comment: it not handle this: <A HrEF="lol" class="dude lol">testings2</a> <A HReF="lol2">blabla</a> :'-( fiiix pleeeeease

Comment: it still fails due to class attribute

Answer (score 0):

not sure how to apply this in PhP but it works in perl

```
/<a href="([^"]+)".+/i;
```

I assume it to be

```
preg_match( '/<a href="([^"]+)".+/i;', $str, $matches);
```